# Ajax events error when sending multiple http request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

- when i'm try to get data for some html element from a website by ajax i added some events like `xhr.onloadstart`,`xhr.onloadend` to show the loader element before sending the request and adding the data after finishing the response and hide the loader
- the problem is when i try to click on multiple elements after each other it's just stop working just display the load for some html elements and not given any data and that's happening just when i try to click on 3 or 4 element after each other directly - and when i click normally and wait for load it's working without any problems -- i don't know if the problem is with my code or the problem in ajax like it's cannot handle many requests at the same time ... Please anyone help me
- i was working with jquery ajax and changed to the XMLHttpRequest() and the problem still the same

> Here's my code

```
for(let q = 0; q < elem.length; q++) {
 elem[q].addEventListener("click",function() {
   let url = $(this).find(".elem").attr("href");
   let _this = this;
   let $this = $(this);
   var xh = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xh.onloadstart = function(bubbles) {
     _this.getElementsByClassName("loader")[0].style.display = 'block';
   }
   xh.onreadystatechange = function(change) {
     _this.getElementsByClassName("loader")[0].style.display = 'none';
   }
xh.onloadend = function(data) {
     console.log(data)
     //result dom object
     console.log($(data.currentTarget.responseText)[71].getElementsByClassName("row").length)
     
     if($(data.currentTarget.responseText)[71].getElementsByClassName("row").length > 0) {
       let row = $(data.currentTarget.responseText)[71].getElementsByClassName("row")[0].getElementsByClassName("row")[0];    
       let select_color = $(row).find("#container #color_select_options").attr("class","ElemData");
       $this.append(select_color[0]);
//when user click again delete appended element and keep the first one
       if($this.find(".ElemData").length > 1) {
         for(o = 1; o < $this.find(".ElemData").length; o++) {                             
           _this.getElementsByClassName("ElemData")[o].remove()
         }   
       }
     }
 })
}
```

Comment: You include jQuery in your tags but your trying to roll your own async requests (XMLHttpRequest).  I would use jQuery's $.ajax({ ... });

Comment: I was using jQuery ajax but changed to XMLHttpRequest() - i thought that maybe the problem was with jQuery ajax but anyway the jQuery library is already in my document and i can use it in anything i wants to i think it doesn't matter if i'm using jQuery methods with XMLHttpRequest()

Comment: i also tried fetch() api and all is the same i should to click on one then wait untill it's load then click on the other one .... And when i try to click on more than one at the same time it's just left the old requests and excute the last request why they cannot handle all the request which means that they are finish the old request then move to the new Request but it's just leave all the old requests without finishing it and move to the new requests